# How to set monthcalendar (c#) to be readonly?

Tags: c#, date, readonly, monthcalendar

There's some way to make monthcalendar control in C# (Windows forms)  not editable for the user?

I'm looking for some code like:

```
myMonthcalendar.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
myMonthcalendar.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myMonthcalendar.Enabled = false;
```